# PHP - Return only unique values from multi-array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, while-loop, distinct

My array contains the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Events - Central [1] => Central [2] => Finance [3] => 17 [5] => 11 [8] => 11  )
Array ( [0] => Events - Central [1] => Central [2] => HR [3] => 17 [5] => 11 [8] => 11 )
Array ( [0] => Events - Central [1] => Central [2] => IT [3] => 17 [5] => 11 [8] => 11  )
Array ( [0] => Events - Central [1] => London [2] => Sales [3] => 17 [5] => 11 [8] => 11  )
Array ( [0] => Events - Central [1] => London [2] => Marketing [3] => 17 [5] => 11 [8] => 11 )
Array ( [0] => Events - Central [1] => London [2] => HR [3] => 17 [5] => 11 [8] => 11  )
Array ( [0] => Piloting [1] => London [2] => HR [3] => 17 [5] => 11 [8] => 11  )
Array ( [0] => Piloting [1] => London [2] => IT [3] => 17 [5] => 11 [8] => 11  )
```

Now, using a simple `WHILE` loop allows me to loop through the array and I can easily extract the information I need but I'm struggling because I need to bring back distinct values (and I cannot change the `SQL` code).

The output would be a simple table like this, but notice that level 1 and 2 of the table are not repeated:

```
Events - Central          17
    Central               17
        Finance           11
        HR                 1
        IT                 1
    London                28
        Sales             17
        Marketing          2
        HR                 5
Piloting                  37
    London                37
       HR                 30
       IT                  7
```

In short, I'm trying to bring back `distinct` instances - if that makes sense?

Is this even possible without deconstructing the array?

I'm very concious that I may not have illustrated/ framed this question well.

Comment: So array positions 0,1 and 2 have the "headings" but where do the numbers come from. I see they're in the rest of the array "somewhere" but I can't see any clear logic behind them.

Comment: Can You Please Give me a simple array with these values ?

Comment: Apols - I can see it's not clear.  It's positions 3, 5 and 8 - note that the numbers I reference in the table example won't match the Array - they are both for example purposes.

Comment: What fields are supposed to be unique?

Comment: If you don't provide example output that matches the example input, we're probably not going to be able to help.

Comment: Tidied up the array to try and make it clearer @kloddant - the elemens that are unique and should only be shown once are in array [0] and [1] positions.  So I only want to show Events - Central once and not the six times it appears in the array,

Comment: *Is this even possible without deconstructing the array?* - i think you need to build temporary array with 3 levels

Comment: You need to provide input and output that matches if you want answers that will work. Likewise SO is not a code writing service and you should provide what you have attempted and where the issues are. For example your title is something about uniqueness but the question does not demonstrate a need for this at all...

Comment: @nerdlyist thanks for the feedback do appreciate is as I did state that I wasn't sure if I phrased the question correctly.  As I have replied to kloddant above - the example shows which are the unique elements, although I accept this could have been clearer in the question.  I can see that apokryfos has provided a response below which is extremely helpful and also appreciated but above I do state that I can use a simple while loop to extract the data and then I ask if, what I am trying to achieve, is actually even possible without deconstructing the array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do to (a) echo the data you need and (b) create an array with said data vaguely arranged in a way you can work with:

```
<?php
$superArray = [
    [ "Events - Central", "Central", "Finance",   17, 0, 11, 0, 0, 11, 0 ],
    [ "Events - Central", "Central", "HR",        17, 0, 11, 0, 0, 11, 0 ],
    [ "Events - Central", "Central", "IT",        17, 0, 11, 0, 0, 11, 0 ],
    [ "Events - Central", "London",  "Sales",     17, 0, 11, 0, 0, 11, 0 ], 
    [ "Events - Central", "London",  "Marketing", 17, 0, 11, 0, 0, 11, 0 ],
    [ "Events - Central", "London",  "HR",        17, 0, 11, 0, 0, 11, 0 ],
    [ "Piloting",         "London",  "HR",        17, 0, 11, 0, 0, 11, 0  ],
    [ "Piloting",         "London",  "IT",        17, 0, 11, 0, 0, 11, 0 ]
];



usort($superArray, function ($a,$b) {
    return $a[0] == $b[0] && $a[1]==$b[1]
        ? $a[2]<=>$b[2]
        : (
            $a[0] == $b[0]
            ?$a[1]<=>$b[1]
            :$a[0]<=>$b[0]
        );
});

$lastSeen = [];
$buildArray = [];

foreach ($superArray as $array) {

    if (!isset($lastSeen[0]) || $lastSeen[0] != $array[0]) {
        $lastSeen[0] = $array[0];
        $lastSeen[1] = null;
        echo $array[0]."\t".$array[3].PHP_EOL;
        $buildArray[]= [
            "level" => 0,
            "name" => $array[0],
            "value" => $array[3]
        ];
    }
    if (!isset($lastSeen[1]) || $lastSeen[1] != $array[1]) {
        $lastSeen[1] = $array[1];
        $lastSeen[2] = null;
        echo "\t".$array[1]."\t".$array[5].PHP_EOL;
        $buildArray[]= [
            "level" => 1,
            "name" => $array[1],
            "value" => $array[5]
        ];

    }
    if (!isset($lastSeen[2]) || $lastSeen[2] != $array[2]) {
        $lastSeen[2] = $array[2];
        echo "\t\t".$array[2]."\t".$array[8].PHP_EOL;
        $buildArray[]= [
            "level" => 2,
            "name" => $array[2],
            "value" => $array[8]
        ];

    }

}


print_r($buildArray);
```

This will print:

```
Events - Central    17
    Central 11
        Finance 11
        HR  11
        IT  11
    London  11
        HR  11
        Marketing   11
        Sales   11
Piloting    17
    London  11
        HR  11
        IT  11
```

The array structure will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [level] => 0
            [name] => Events - Central
            [value] => 17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [level] => 1
            [name] => Central
            [value] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
            [name] => Finance
            [value] => 11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
            [name] => HR
            [value] => 11
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
            [name] => IT
            [value] => 11
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [level] => 1
            [name] => London
            [value] => 11
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
            [name] => HR
            [value] => 11
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
            [name] => Marketing
            [value] => 11
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
            [name] => Sales
            [value] => 11
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [level] => 0
            [name] => Piloting
            [value] => 17
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [level] => 1
            [name] => London
            [value] => 11
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
            [name] => HR
            [value] => 11
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
            [name] => IT
            [value] => 11
        )
```

)

The idea is to first put all arrays in a combined array and then sort according to the priorities (I think they're already sorted though). Having done that you keep track on what you've seen for each level and re-construct an array based on that.

Keep in mind this is very hard-coded stuff but you could probably generalize it if you need to.

Example at: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf92828a5561d59d503e5765cc6b566a5acc0532

Comment: Incredibly helpful - thank you.  I think, without being able to change the query, I'm looking at deconstructing the array and/ hard coding as you say.  However, the above really helps. Thanks and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different take on apokryfos's answer, but a similar concept. The idea is to use the de-duping ability of array keys in PHP to build up the hierarchical array:

```
$data = [];
$data[] = [0 => 'Events - Central', 1 => 'Central', 2 => 'Finance', 3 => 17, 5 => 11, 8 => 11];
$data[] = [0 => 'Events - Central', 1 => 'Central', 2 => 'HR', 3 => 17, 5 => 11, 8 => 11];
$data[] = [0 => 'Events - Central', 1 => 'Central', 2 => 'IT', 3 => 17, 5 => 11, 8 => 11];
$data[] = [0 => 'Events - Central', 1 => 'London', 2 => 'Sales', 3 => 17, 5 => 11, 8 => 11];
$data[] = [0 => 'Events - Central', 1 => 'London', 2 => 'Marketing', 3 => 17, 5 => 11, 8 => 11];
$data[] = [0 => 'Events - Central', 1 => 'London', 2 => 'HR', 3 => 17, 5 => 11, 8 => 11];
$data[] = [0 => 'Piloting', 1 => 'London', 2 => 'HR', 3 => 17, 5 => 11, 8 => 11];
$data[] = [0 => 'Piloting', 1 => 'London', 2 => 'IT', 3 => 17, 5 => 11, 8 => 11];

$tree_root = [];

// map the keys in the $data array to each other
$caption_to_value_mapping = [
    0 => 3,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 8
];

foreach ($data as $datum) {
    $sub_tree = &$tree_root;
    foreach ($caption_to_value_mapping as $level_index => $value) {
        $caption = $datum[$level_index];
        if (!isset($sub_tree[$caption])) {
            $sub_tree[$caption] = ['next_level' => []];
        }
        $sub_tree[$caption]['caption'] = $caption;
        $sub_tree[$caption]['value'] = $datum[$value];
        $sub_tree = &$sub_tree[$caption]['next_level'];
    }
}

var_dump($tree_root);
```

You can then use $tree_root in a recursive function to build the display of the data.

Note that this is generic and will take any number of levels, as long as the $caption_to_value_mapping is maintained.